# Adresse IP to EDX using TUTOR

Tags: edx

please can someone help me to know how I can make an address IP to EDX using tutor?

It is in a file or can I configure it in line of command or in file (for file CONFIG.YML ???) this configuration if for CMS and LMS.

Thanks.